# Is there a way to pause a specific CSS3 animation

Tags: css, sass, css-animations

I want to do something like the code below does but instead of having it "teleport" to the center I wish I could pause just one animation and keep the others running, in other words the element should stop wherever it is because the `pass` animation is paused, but the `anim` and `force-stop` animations should start running.

```css
body {
  background: #121212;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.input {
  transition: 100ms ease;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1.2px solid #383838;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
.input .blaster {
  position: absolute;
  transition: 100ms ease;
  background: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 30% auto;
  filter: blur(3px);
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: anim 2s ease infinite,pass 500ms linear infinite;
  top: -150px;
}
.input > span {
  transition: 100ms ease;
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
  color: #aaa;
}
.input:hover {
  animation: move 100ms ease infinite;
  border-color: #eee;
  background-color: #272727;
}
.input:hover > .blaster {
  animation: anim 2s ease infinite,move 100ms ease infinite;
}
.input:hover > span {
  color: transparent;
}

@keyframes anim {
  from {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #fff,0px 0px 10px 3px #f33,0 0 15px 3px #f33;
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #fff,0px 0px 16px 3px #f33,0 0 15px 5px #f33;
  }
  to {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #fff,0px 0px 10px 3px #f33,0 0 15px 3px #f33;
  }
}
@keyframes pass {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-600px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(600px);
  }
}
@keyframes move {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateX(2.24px);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateX(-1.75px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="input">
  <span>Hover me</span>
  <div class="blaster"></div>
</div>
```

I tried using `animation-play-state` but it pauses all animations.
Also I would prefer to do this in pure SCSS/CSS3 if possible but if there is a simple way to do it in JavaScript or jQuery it's acceptable too.
Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:** I've made some janky styles in that snippet so unfortunately it only works in full-page.

Comment: have you considered setting it to a really really really slow speed to mimic a pause and then set it to normal animation speed when you want it to start again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider `animation-play-state` by simply writing:

```
.input:hover > .blaster {
  animation-play-state:running,paused;
}
```

Full code

```css
body {
  background: #121212;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.input {
  transition: 100ms ease;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1.2px solid #383838;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
.input .blaster {
  position: absolute;
  transition: 100ms ease;
  background: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 30% auto;
  filter: blur(3px);
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: anim 2s ease infinite,pass 500ms linear infinite;
  top: -150px;
}
.input > span {
  transition: 100ms ease;
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
  color: #aaa;
}
.input:hover {
  animation: move 100ms ease infinite;
  border-color: #eee;
  background-color: #272727;
}
.input:hover > .blaster {
  animation-play-state:running,paused;
}
.input:hover > span {
  color: transparent;
}

@keyframes anim {
  from {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #fff,0px 0px 10px 3px #f33,0 0 15px 3px #f33;
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #fff,0px 0px 16px 3px #f33,0 0 15px 5px #f33;
  }
  to {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #fff,0px 0px 10px 3px #f33,0 0 15px 3px #f33;
  }
}
@keyframes pass {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-600px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(600px);
  }
}
@keyframes move {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateX(2.24px);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateX(-1.75px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="input">
  <span>Hover me</span>
  <div class="blaster"></div>
</div>
```